# Background worker for android to be always

Tags: java, android

i need to create a background thread , that check for information from Server on every 20 minutes and make notification if we have news. Any ideas how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can execute a background thread infinitely for doing so or simply use Google cloud messaging push notification service

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Service` for that.

> A service is a component which runs in the background without direct interaction with the user. As the service has no user interface, it is not bound to the lifecycle of an activity.
>
> Services are used for repetitive and potentially long running operations, i.e., Internet downloads, checking for new data, data processing, updating content providers and the like.

Here is the Documentation for that [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

And for tutorial Check this [Android Service Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

[The android service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) please have a look

Answer (score -2):

you can use while loop i think i don't know too much about server connection but if you can pass boolean or specific string from the and inside the service class of your app create a while true like this:

```
while(true){

  if(ServerString.contentEquals("") || boolean == true{
     //coding

     }
     try{
        Tread.sleep(60)}
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace }

   }
```

the fastest way of learning a service in here video [made by a girl](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAOH7XTW7BU)

Comment: Please don't take this approach. You'd be making a severe mistake!